# Rotation changing objects position using QField

Tags: qfield

I have a QField map with pipes and objects (water hydrant, stand pipe) in QField. Unfortunately, the objects change their position as soon as I rotate the map with 2 fingers (e.g. by 15 degrees).

Can I prevent the map from rotating or is there another solution?

The objects are integrated as a font.

[image][image]

Comment: Other people also wanted to be able to disable rotation, seems like it is not implemented yet: https://github.com/opengisch/QField/discussions/4040 .

Comment: Pressing north reorients and fixes the map (as a workaround). Thx til_b